Compatibility Issue: WSO2 MI 4.1 with MongoDB Connector v2.0.0 and MongoDB 6.x Driver
I am trying to use the MongoDB connector with WSO2 Micro Integrator (MI) 4.1 following the provided steps  (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.2.0/reference/connectors/mongodb-connector/mongodb-connector-example/)
However, I encounter a ClassNotFoundException when attempting to connect to MongoDB using the 6.x driver.
Details:

WSO2 MI Version: 4.1
MongoDB Connector Version: 2.0.0
MongoDB Driver Version: 6.x

Issue: ClassNotFoundException
Steps Taken:
Followed the MongoDB connector example in the WSO2 documentation.
Placed the MongoDB driver JAR files in the lib directory.
Verified the classpath configuration in WSO2 MI.
Despite these steps, the exception persists.
Questions:
Is WSO2 MI 4.1 compatible with MongoDB 6.x drivers?
Are there any known compatibility issues or additional configurations required for this setup?
Would upgrading to a newer version of WSO2 MI resolve this issue?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Additional Steps for MongoDB Connector v2.0.0 or Above:
Downloaded the following JARs and added them in to the <PRODUCT_HOME>/dropins folder:

mongodb-driver-syn
bson
mongodb-driver-core

Despite these steps, the exception persists.

Shall we try this jar file and see. It worked with MongoDB 7.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.2

mongo-Java-driver: 3.12.2 with MongoDBconnector 2.0.0 working for WSO2 with MongoDB 6.x
Thanks for the response

Ive done the same , but while inserting im getting this error -  Sequence template org.wso2.carbon.connector.mongodb.insertOne cannot be found
Any idea ?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
